# smbclient every time force to enter username and password which doesnt have any authentication(i.e public) on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, passwords, smb, smbclient

I am using smbclient to browse though the shared network which doesnt have any username and password.

```
smbclient //Server/share -U username password\   //Good
```

**This is good when a server is protected with username and passwod**

Problem is when  one try to access sharefolder which is public (don't have username and password).

I find as below command after googling for a long time but its not working.

```
smbclient //Server/share -U " "%" " // BAD
```

**error : session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE**

how can i access share which doesn't have password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find the solution as if one want to login which doesn't have any credential.you must not use -U

```
smbclient //SERVER/Share
```

Hit enter you are in.